# проверка на наличие папки

Tags: javascript, jquery

через jquery проверяю на наличие папки

```
for (var i=1;i<=100;i++){
    $.post( "http://192.168.100.67/vtnuft/group"+i+"/check.php", function(response){
      response = JSON.parse(response);
      $.each(response, function( key, val ) {
          if(key === "check" && val === true){
              console.log(key,val,i);
                informationArray.push(i);}
          else if(key === "check" && val === false){
              console.log(i,"false");
          }
      });
    });  
}
```

Но в informationArray сохраняются 101 столько раз сколько нашло пхп с виходом
    {'check' => true}

В чем причина такого поведения?

Comment: Причина в том, что _$.post_ асинхронная операция

Comment: @Grundy нет, не в этом

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в этом в этом, когда выполняется callback для post, цикл уже закончен и значение `i` - 101

Comment: @Grundy проблема общая для комбинации "замыкание + цикл" и не имеет отношения к асинхронности.

Comment: то как решить проблему не написав сто раз post-метод

Comment: @PavelMayorov, что не отменяет того что я сказал - если бы функция выполнялась сразу - ошибки бы не было

Comment: @МиколаКікець зависит от того что вы хотите добиться проверив папки и что после этого хотите сделать ... ведь банально можно наличие папки проверить на сервере..один раз послав запрос с `Range` что проверять.. например наличие папки от 1 до 50... все зависит от задачи ) ....... я вот лично не стал бы бомбить сервак 100 запросами на наличие папки....

Comment: просто делается для проверки груп в школьном заведении го я не знаю сколько груп находится в нем

Comment: @МиколаКікець на стороне сервера можно проверить и сколько папок в директории и какие и даже отфильтровать по любому условию. всё что душе угодно. но это лично как я вижу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы используете в каждом замыкании одну и ту же переменную i - которая меняется. Чтобы сохранить значение переменной неизменным - надо создать новый контекст путем вызова анонимной функции.

Вот один из способов:

```
for (var i=1; i<=100; i++)
  !function(i) {
    // $.post(... и т.д.
  }(i);
```

Что за магия тут происходит?

`function(i) { ... }` - это объявление анонимной функции, принимающей параметр `i`. Этот параметр скрывает внешнюю переменную `i`.

`function(i) { ... }(i)` - это вызов объявленной анонимной функции, с передачей ей значения переменной `i` как параметра. Теперь внутри функции параметр `i` равен тому значению, которое имела переменная `i` на момент вызова. Теперь цикл может пройти дальше, значение переменной `i` изменится на 101 - но внутри анонимной функции значение параметра `i` останется неизменным.

`!function(i) { ... }(i)` - это один из способов написать прошлый вариант так, чтобы интерпретатор понял, что это именно выражение. Дело в том, что если строка начинается со слова `function` - интерпретатор будет считать его определением именной функции, и будет синтаксическая ошибка. Чтобы этого избежать, к выражению добавляется любая операция.

Допустимы также такие варианты конструкции:

- `~function(i) { ... }(i)`
- `+function(i) { ... }(i)`
- `-function(i) { ... }(i)`
- `1/function(i) { ... }(i)`
- `(function(i) { ... })(i)`
- `(function(i) { ... }(i))`

Еще один вариант - обернуть в анонимную функцию не тело цикла целиком - а только функцию обратного вызова, передающуюся в `$.post`:

```
for (var i=1; i<=100; i++)
  $.post("http://192.168.100.67/vtnuft/group"+i+"/check.php", function (i) {
    return function (responce) {
      // ...
    }
  }(i))
```

Тут анонимная функция находится не в самом начале строки - а потому никаких хитростей не требуется. Выбирайте тот вариант, который нравится.

Comment: мне кажется проще было вернуть номер группы с сервера :-D

Comment: отличный ответ. Чтобы не пропал, переформулируйте, пожалуйста, заголовок вопроса ТС (и тело вопроса, в идеале), так, чтобы его легко нашли при похожей проблеме. Нынешняя формулировка «проверка на наличие папки» – совершенно misleading.